# Eliminate the need for "break" & "while true"

Tags: python

I have been instructed that my current code is complete, but the use of "while true" and "break" statements is not acceptable.  I am under the impression that I can instead use conditions to end loops, but I am currently having trouble implementing this.  Any suggestions or criticisms are welcome :)

```
import random
def roll_dice():
return random.randint(1,6)

players = ['Player One', 'Player Two']
scores = {'Player One': 0, 'Player Two': 0}
random.shuffle(players)

while True:
    for i in players:
        if i == 'Player One':
            choice = input("Roll(r) or Hold(h)?: ")
            turn_score = 0
            final_score = 0
            if (choice=='r'):
                while(turn_score<=20):
                    dice_value = roll_dice()
                    turn_score += dice_value
                    if dice_value == 1:
                        turn_score = 0
                        print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
                        print("Pigged out!")
                        break
                    print("Turn score is: ", turn_score)
                    print("Your final score is: ", final_score + turn_score)
                    if final_score + turn_score > 100:
                        final_score += turn_score
                        break
        else:
            turn_score=0
            print("It is " +  str(i) + "'s turn.")
            while(turn_score<20):
                dice_value = roll_dice()
                if (dice_value==1):
                    turn_score = 0
                    scores[i] +=0
                    print("- rolled a ",dice_value)
                    print("Pigged out!")
                    break
                else:
                    turn_score+=dice_value
                    print("-rolled a ",dice_value)
        scores[i] += turn_score
        print("Turn score is: ",turn_score)
        print('{} score: {} {} score: {}'.format(players[0], scores[players[0]], players[1], 
scores[players[1]]))
        if scores[i]>100:
            break
    if scores[i]>100:
        break

winner = [winner for winner in scores if scores[winner] == max(scores.values())]
print(str(winner) + " is the winner!")
```

Comment: Introduce a boolean variable like ```isGameOver = False```. This should be declared before the while loop. In your while instead of ```while True:``` you can check ```while not isGameOver:``` and inside the while loop, if ```scores[i] > 100: isGameOver = True```. That will quit the main while loop

Comment: @ArunSubramanian: Avoid answering questions in comments, especially when they involve posting code.

Comment: @martineau Gotcha! Apologies!

Comment: Did they explain why `while true` and `break` are unacceptable? Sometimes, they're the best way to write a loop, so I hope the complaint is specific to this code.

Comment: I was informed that it is easier to read code when it is structured around an end point instead of using "While true" and "break" to decide an arbitrary end. @luther

Comment: It's unfortunate that your code reviewer or teacher has this policy. `while True` makes it clear that at least part of the loop must run at least once. `if` -- `break` makes it clear where the exiting condition arises. If you create a boolean variable to pass the exit decision back to the top, you obscure both of these things and make more spaghetti code.

Comment: I've written a lot of answers on Code Review and have found Python's 'do while' loops to be a perfectly fine pattern. In many cases a do while loop really does make the code that bit easier to understand. That said, some advice I got when I was a student; if your teacher says something is unacceptable getting points is more important than being right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only significant problem I see is that the `scores[i]>100` gets repeated. You can fix that by rolling the two outermost loops into one.

First, define this generator before the loop:

```
def takeTurns():
    """Loop through players over and over again."""
    while True:
        yield from players
```

Then change the first `while` and `for` statements into this:

```
for i in takeTurns():
    # Do the stuff that was in `for i in players:`.

    # Do this check only once.
    if scores[i]>100:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the input.  This has helped me on my way to resolving this issue.  Although my goal is to not use "break" at all.

Answer (score 2):

Introduce a boolean variable to check if the game is over and use that to control your while loop. Something like this:

```
players = ['Player One', 'Player Two']
scores = {'Player One': 0, 'Player Two': 0}
random.shuffle(players)

isGameOver = False  # This is a boolean to track the game.

while not isGameOver: # isGameOver is False as long as the game is not over
    for i in players:
        if i == 'Player One':
            #Code for Player 1 as you have.
        else:
            #Code for Player 2 as you have.
        scores[i] += turn_score
        print("Turn score is: ",turn_score)
        print('{} score: {} {} score: {}'.format(players[0], scores[players[0]], players[1], scores[players[1]]))
        if scores[i] > 100:
            break
    if scores[i] > 100:
        isGameOver = True # This is Game Over as we have one player whose score is greater than 100. So set the isGameOver to True which will terminate the loop

winner = [winner for winner in scores if scores[winner] == max(scores.values())]
print(str(winner) + " is the winner!")
```

Comment: You wouldn't need the second `if scores[i] > 100:` if you set `isGameOver` before the `break` in the first.

Comment: This code doesn't seem to function.  I believe I understand the concept you're trying to explain, but it's difficult to apply as I can't directly compare functionality.  Best Regards,

Comment: The code obviously doesn't function because I haven't added every code that you already posted. In the Code for Player 1 as you have, just add the code that you already wrote. I don't want to copy paste the same code again. The logic is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to take a step back from the code and describe the problem that this `while` loop is trying to solve in words. It looks like you are writing code for some kind of game. So what are the conditions that end the game? First describe that condition in words. Then figure out how you can translate those words into an expression in Python.

Comment: The main condition is that once either player reaches 100 points the game ends.  Otherwise each player alternates rolling the "dice" until 100 points is reached.  If you roll anything other than 0 you can keep rolling until a 0 point roll is achieved.

Comment: @HunterBabcock So the next step is to translate those words into code. How can you write a `while` condition that checks if either player is over 100 points?